# KMM iOS crashes because `Flow` does not correct throw, Exception doesn't match @Throws-specified class

Tags: swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have the following method returning Flow

```
@Throws(Throwable::class) fun getPokemon(): Flow<PokemonList> {
        try {
            return flow {
                throw Exception("Hello")
                emit(api.getFirstPagePokedex())
            }
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            throw e
        }
    }
```

where api.getFirstPagePokedex is a suspend fun with signature `suspend fun getFirstPagePokedex(): PokemonList`.

When I call `getPokemon()` in Swift, I'm faced with this error

```
Exception doesn't match @Throws-specified class list and thus isn't propagated from Kotlin to Objective-C/Swift as NSError.
It is considered unexpected and unhandled instead. Program will be terminated.
Uncaught Kotlin exception: kotlin.Exception: Hello
```

If I move throw `Exception("Hello")` outside flow block then the iOS version works fine. But it would not catch the error from `api.getFirstPagePokedex()` as it should.

```
@Throws(Throwable::class) fun getPokemon(): Flow<PokemonList> {
        try {
            throw Exception("Hello")
            return flow {
                emit(api.getFirstPagePokedex())
            }
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            throw e
        }
    }
```

How can we catch exception from `flow` block correctly for Swift?

Please note that all cases works as expected on Android with no crash.

Comment: with flow you can use `catch` to handle exception like `flow{}.catch { exception ->  }`

Comment: tried couple variants of `flow{}.catch {throw it}`, with/without `try/catch`, without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `getPokemon()`, all you're doing is creating the flow. The code inside the flow doesn't get executed until later, when you collect the flow.

You can actually remove the `@Throws` annotation from `getPokemon()`, as that method itself won't throw the exception. You should instead add the annotation to any method where you collect items from the flow.

Comment: Following this advice, I created another fun which works as expected: `@OptIn(InternalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Throws(Exception::class) suspend fun getPokemonIOS(collector: FlowCollector<PokemonList>) {
        getPokemon().collect(collector)
    }`